# Running DTA on a particular database on all tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get index recommendations for a database. However it is giving me drop index scripts and no create scripts. How do we choose the work load table when we choose a whole database? Can somebody please let me know how we can choose.

Also how do we create index on a particular database on all tables. I mean what is the basis? How do we select clustered and non-clustered. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's telling you to drop indexes only then the SQL it is seeing run does not justify the creation of new indexes to improve performance (in DTA's humble opinion).  Are you sure indexes will help improve performance?  Rather than throwing indexes at it, I would recommend:

1. identifying problem queries
2. looking at the execution plan for those queries
3. use what you find in the execution plan as the basis for how you will improve performance.

You don't create indexes on all tables in the database.  You create an index on a table itself.